# RequestBatch.Callback onBatchCompleted() not called

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having trouble using facebook graph API library for android when sending a batch of requests.

Not getting a callback when running this code:

```
        RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch(requests);
        requestBatch.addCallback(new com.facebook.RequestBatch.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onBatchCompleted(RequestBatch batch) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onBatchCompleted()");
            }
        });
        requestBatch.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

You need to set the callback for each individual request to get the batch-related callback, because onBatchCompleted callback will be called after all per-Request callbacks are called..

```
        for (String friend : friends) {
            MyLog.d(LOG_TAG, "Adding request for " + friend.getInterestFbId());
            String graphPath = friend + "/feed";
            Request request = new Request(session, graphPath, null, HttpMethod.GET);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields",
                             "id,"+
                             "name,"+
                             "username,"+
                             "feed,");
            request.setParameters(params);


            // THIS IS VITAL OR THE BATCH CALLBACK WILL NEVER ARRIVE            
            request.setCallback(new com.facebook.Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {}
            });


            requests.add(request);

        }
```

Comment: meh, have to wait 2 days :(

Comment: how do you get response from RequestBatch ?